# If $f(x) = \frac{x}{x - \frac{1}{f(x)}}$, then what is the fixed point of $f(f(x))$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, recursion, fixed-point-iteration

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $x>1$.

Here is my question:

> What is the <s>[**fixed point**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics))</s> of $f(f(x))$ if $$f(x) = \dfrac{x}{x - \dfrac{1}{f(x)}}?$$

**My Attempt**

$$f(f(x)) = \dfrac{x}{x - \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{x}{x - \dfrac{1}{f(x)}}}} = \dfrac{x}{x - \dfrac{x - \dfrac{1}{f(x)}}{x}} = \dfrac{x^2}{x^2 - x + \dfrac{1}{f(x)}}$$
$$f(f(x))=f(x) \iff f(x) = \dfrac{x}{x - \dfrac{1}{f(x)}}$$

Solving for $f(x)$, we obtain
$$f(x) = \frac{xf(x)}{xf(x) - 1}$$
so that
$$x(f(x))^2 - f(x) = xf(x).$$
It follows that
$$x(f(x))^2 = (x+1)f(x).$$
Since $f(x) \neq 0$, we can cancel $f(x)$ from both sides, and thereby get
$$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x}=1+\frac{1}{x}.$$

We therefore conclude that the fixed point of $f(f(x))$ is
$$f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x}.$$

> Is my interpretation of the word *fixed point* in the context of this question correct?

**Update (September 25 2016 - 12:32 AM)** Per a comment from [b00n heT](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/119285), I should not use the term <s>"*fixed point*"</s>.  A follow-up question of mine would then be:  What terminology should I use?

Comment: A fixed point of a function, is a point $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$. In your case the function is $f\circ f$ so the starting equation should read
$$f(f(x))=x,$$
which is not what you tried to solve.

Comment: @b00nheT, thank you for your clarificatory comment.  I actually meant to solve the equation $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for $f(x)$, which happens to be the same as solving for $f(x)$ in the equation
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x - \frac{1}{f(x)}}.$$

So my follow-up question would be:  What should be the appropriate terminology that I should use?  Per your comment, it definitely is not going to be a *fixed point*.

Comment: Now I understand. Well, it's actually nothing but the pre-image of the set of fixed points of $f$, under $f$. Thus I don't think a new term is needed.

Comment: I don't understand; you say that the fixed point of the function $f(f(x))$ is the function $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x}$?

Comment: @Winther, what I am saying is that, if
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x - \frac{1}{f(x)}}$$
then $f(f(x))=f(x)$, and $f(x)=1+(1/x)$.  What I am not sure about (which is why I am asking so in this question) is whether $f(x)=1+(1/x)$ can be interpreted to be a *fixed point* of $f(f(x))$?

Comment: Ok, but that is wrong right. If $f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$ then $f(f(x)) = 1 + \frac{x}{1+x} \not= f(x)$ unless $x= \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. You are correct that $f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$ solves the initial equation though. The only fixed points of $f(x)$ and therefore of $f(f(x))$ (and $f(f(f(x)))$ and so on) is $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Comment: I am (of course) aware that $x_0 = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the value $x_0$ that makes $f(f(x_0))=f(x_0)$ when $f(x)=1+(1/x)$.  However, please read my question again.  Towards the end, I ask if my interpretation of the word *fixed point* is correct in the context of my solution attempt in the question.  So, if I should not use the terminology "*fixed point*" (that is, if it is the wrong term to use), what is the appropriate terminology for $f(x)=1+(1/x)$ given the context of the solution attempt here?

Comment: Calculation of $f(f(x)))$ gives a function that is not contractant so if there is a fixed point it is not necessarily unique. In your case you have two ones: $x=\frac{1\pm \sqrt5}{2}$

Comment: Terminology for what? You have removed "fixed point" from the problem description so it's hard to guess what you acctually is supposed to compute. From your calculations it seems you have just computed the function $f(x)$ that solves your equation. The detour via $f(f(x))$ is uneccessary: you can just solve for $f(x)$ directly.

Comment: Hmmm.  Looking at my tags, I see **recursion**.  So I guess what I meant was that:  How do you call the **unique function** $f(x)$ that satisfies the recursion relation
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x-\frac{1}{f(x)}}?$$

Additionally, since this definition for $f(x)$ gives rise to
$$\cdots = f(f(f(x))) = f(f(x)) = f(x),$$
and since the definition of a **fixed point** requires $f(x)=x$, then definitely I cannot call $f(x)$ here a fixed point.

Comment: Can I call it an **initial seed function**?

Comment: I don't know why you insist on talking about functions when the equation system you have is only true at a single point. If $f(x) = \frac{x}{x - \frac{1}{f(x)}}$ then we have that $f(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$ for all $x$. However when you impose that $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ and $x>1$ then this is now only true at a single point $x = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ so calling $f(x)$ a "seed function" is a misleading term as $x$ cannot be anything - it has to be $x = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ in order for this to make sense (which gives rise to the continued fraction for the golden ratio).